# Corona simulator anchor points Y

Tags: lua, coronasdk, anchorpoint

I can't tell if I'm doing something silly or if there is a bug in Corona simulator. When I write the following code:

```
rect = display.newRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
rect.anchorX = 0
rect.anchorY = 0
rect.x = 0
rect.y = 0
```

This just sets the anchor point of a 100x100 square to its top left, and sets the position to 0,0. This should make the square snug in the corner, but instead it produces [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XpK3.jpg). It is always a little too far down in the Y axis, but the X axis functions correctly. Does anyone have a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

With my Corona simulator ([build 2016.2992](https://coronalabs.com/blog/2016/11/16/new-public-build-2016-2992-now-available/)) code works as expected.

```
main.lua

---------------------------------------------

local rect = display.newRect( 0, 0, 100, 100)
rect.anchorX = 0
rect.anchorY = 0
```

First of all check your config.lua file. I think it depends on display resolution. For example, in `letterbox` mode you may have "black bars" on devices with aspect ratios that differ from your content aspect ratio. Read more on Corona  [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/basics/configSettings/index.html#contentscaling).

Below is code from my config.lua file I'm using

```
config.lua

---------------------------------------------

--calculate the aspect ratio of the device
local aspectRatio = display.pixelHeight / display.pixelWidth
application = {
   content = {
      width = aspectRatio >= 1.5 and 800 or math.floor( 1200 / aspectRatio ),
      height = aspectRatio <= 1.5 and 1200 or math.floor( 800 * aspectRatio ),
      scale = "letterBox",
      fps = 30,

      imageSuffix = {
         ["@2x"] = 1.3,
      },
   },
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will look into this!